# Shapefile that is reprojected using dotspatial is different from the original one

Tags: asp.net, geoserver, dotspatial

I have a shapefile with EPSG:32749 that will be inserted to Oracle Database and displayed in geoserver. Before that I want to reproject my shapefile to ESPG:4326 using dotspatial library, here's my code

```
var EXTRACTED_NAME = Server.MapPath("~/upload/shp/example/");
string shapeFilePath = @"\example.shp";
shapeFilePath = EXTRACTED_NAME + shapeFilePath;
Shapefile indexMapFile = Shapefile.OpenFile(shapeFilePath);
indexMapFile.Reproject(KnownCoordinateSystems.Geographic.World.WGS1984);
```

But when I preview in geoserver, my shapefile displayed like this, when the original shapefile like this

[image]

[image]

And my question, why shapefile that is reprojected to EPSG 4326 is different from the original one?

Thanks

Comment: Did you tell geoserver that the projection had changed?

Comment: yes, i filled the SRS with epsg:4326 when i created layer in geoserver

Comment: Oh my bad, it happened because I didn't think that there was an inner ring in the polygon. And how can i get the inner ring from a polygon using dotspatial ?

Comment: no idea I'm afraid, you could use ogr2ogr to fix it

Answer (score 0):

This is a little late, but you should be able to access the inner rings from the geometry.  You might need to cast the IGeometry into IPolygon to specifically work with the inner rings, rather than just as getGeometryN.  The following code hasn't been tested yet, but should at least get you pointed in the right direction.

```
Shapefile file = Shapefile.OpenFile(@"D:\Data\Counties\Counties.shp");
foreach(Feature f in file.Features){
    if(f.Geometry is IPolygon){
        IPolygon p = (IPolygon)f.Geometry;
        Debug.WriteLine("Feature " + f.Fid + "\n");
        foreach(ILineString innerRing in p.InteriorRings){
            // Do stuff with your innerRing
            Debug.WriteLine("Ring length : " + innerRing.Length);
        }
    }
    if (f.Geometry is IMultiPolygon)
    {
        IMultiPolygon multi = (IMultiPolygon)f.Geometry;
        for (int i = 0; i < multi.NumGeometries; i++)
        {
            IGeometry g = multi.GetGeometryN(i);
            if (g is IPolygon)
            {
                IPolygon p = (IPolygon)g;
                foreach (ILineString innerRing in p.InteriorRings)
                {
                    // Do stuff with your innerRing
                }
            }

        }

    }

}
```